# sqlite - Update Value based on number of filled in values when editing database

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to have a field in a `sqlite` database that contains how many fields are not null for a series of data.

Its due to each entry can have up to 10 options which are set as fields eg.

```
ID, Option1, Option2, Option3...
```

What I am looking to do is to have a field called OptionCount that reflects how many options that data row has, so if it only had option 1 and 2 with values entered this field would say 2. Then if I added data into option 3 it would auto update this entry to 3 and so on.

I have done some research and it appears that maybe using a trigger would be the way to go, but my knowledge of `sqlite` stops there. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case`:

```
select t.*,
       ( (case when option1 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when option2 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
         (case when option3 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
         . . . 
       ) as num_options_set
. . .
```

Note:  You should be storing the options in a separate table, with one row per  and per option.

In SQLite, the `case` is not necessary, so you can also write this as:

```
select t.*,
       ( (option1 is not null) +
         (option2 is not null) +
         (option3 is not null) +
         . . . 
       ) as num_options_set
. . .
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help. This is what i have so far, ignore the // as thats what im trying to do just struggling with the full trigger a bit.

    `CREATE TRIGGER SiteOptions
    after update on SiteOptions
    begin
    //Update modified rows option count with below
    select SiteOptions.OptionCount((SiteOptions.Option1ID is not null) +
    (SiteOptions.Option2ID is not null) +
    (SiteOptions.Option3ID is not null) +
    (SiteOptions.Option4ID is not null) +
    (SiteOptions.Option5ID is not null)) as SiteOptions.OptionCount
    End`